# Why is it called isolate scope and not isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Isolate is a verb so to say "an isolate scope" is like saying "an eat apple".

Why is it called isolate scope and not isolated scope?

Comment: i would chalk it up to typos as the main directive docs guide uses both.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: It could be used as a noun, though.

Comment: @Shomz only if you choose to invent such a noun.

Comment: @Ben not true; the word *isolate* is definitely a noun in some contexts. For example, spoken languages with no known relatives are called "language isolates".

Comment: @charlietfl It is in the source code too...

Comment: @Pointy Okay, I learn it can be a noun. But that still leaves the question. Isolate can be a verb or (I now learn) a noun. Not an adjective, per the use in AngularJS.

Comment: I wish I invented it, but sadly... http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/isolate

Comment: @Shomz It is used as an adjective in AngularJS. Whether it can be a noun or not is moot.

Comment: It's actually a [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). :D

Comment: Okay, according to dictionary.com it can also be an adjective. Well I didn't know that. I am going to spell "connection", "connexion" in my next open source project.